# How to disable default enabled box style option?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

The default box style setting for indicators is turned on.
Is there a way to make this box style option default-off in Pinescript?

I couldn't find any information in Pinescript documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not accessible via pinescript.

As a workaround, you can have one `input.bool()` and draw your box if it is set to `true`.

```
in_draw = input.bool(false, "Boxes")

if (in_draw)
    // Draw your box
```